# How to complete Multiple Join within With Query?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, left-join, inner-join

I want to complete an additional Inner Join within the query below but am encountering syntax errors after creating a temporary table and inner joining.

```
WITH myPos
AS (
    SELECT row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY pr_emp_id ORDER BY db_last_upd
            ) AS RowNum
        ,pos.*
    FROM master.s_postn pos
    )

SELECT act.row_id
    ,People.SalesID
FROM master.s_evt_act act
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT myPos.RowNum AS update_count
        ,myPos.db_last_upd
        ,myPos.bu_id
        ,myPos.ou_id
        ,myPos.Name
        ,myPos.pr_emp_id
        ,regexp_extract(myPos.Name, '(\\d+)', 1) AS SalesID
    FROM myPos
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT max(rowNum) maxRowNum
            ,pr_emp_id
        FROM myPos
        GROUP BY pr_emp_id
        ) AS maxPos ON myPos.pr_emp_id = maxPos.pr_emp_id
        AND myPos.rowNum = maxPos.maxRowNum
    WHERE lower(myPos.name) LIKE '% specifictitle %'
    ) AS People ON People.pr_emp_id = act.owner_per_id
```

With the additional data captured in the following query:

```
    SELECT sr_num
        ,owner_per_id
        ,x_cs_mgr_txt
    FROM mastertable.s_srv_req AS req
    WHERE req.x_cs_mgr_txt IS NOT NULL
        AND req.sr_stat_id <> 'Closed'
```

This additional Join would be ON req.owner_per_id = act.owner_per_id

I've done a lot of trial and error and thought I'd as for a little help.

Thanks!

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) PS Part of a [mcve] is a clear specification--a description of how the result you want is a function of the input. But you don't give one. We only have an example so we can only guess what that is. And it's not immediately obvious in this case what a likely guess is.

Comment: Contrary to what you write, you can't really just want that JOIN ON of those two expressions, because neither of the columns in the ON are in the result of the 1st query. So you are not clearly saying what you want even in terms of code involving those expressions. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. PS When giving (base or query result) relation(ship)s/associations or tables say what a row says about the business situation in terms of its column values when it is in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say something more than try this:

```
WITH myPos
AS (
    SELECT row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY pr_emp_id ORDER BY db_last_upd
            ) AS RowNum
        ,pos.*
    FROM master.s_postn pos
    )

SELECT act.row_id
    ,People.SalesID
FROM master.s_evt_act act
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT myPos.RowNum AS update_count
        ,myPos.db_last_upd
        ,myPos.bu_id
        ,myPos.ou_id
        ,myPos.Name
        ,myPos.pr_emp_id
        ,regexp_extract(myPos.Name, '(\\d+)', 1) AS SalesID
    FROM myPos
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT max(rowNum) maxRowNum
            ,pr_emp_id
        FROM myPos
        GROUP BY pr_emp_id
        ) AS maxPos ON myPos.pr_emp_id = maxPos.pr_emp_id
        AND myPos.rowNum = maxPos.maxRowNum
    WHERE lower(myPos.name) LIKE '% specifictitle %'
    ) AS People ON People.pr_emp_id = act.owner_per_id
    INNER JOIN (
    SELECT sr_num
        ,owner_per_id
        ,x_cs_mgr_txt
    FROM mastertable.s_srv_req AS req
    WHERE req.x_cs_mgr_txt IS NOT NULL
        AND req.sr_stat_id <> 'Closed'
    ) AS req  ON req.owner_per_id = act.owner_per_id
```

Comment: Easy enough! Thanks!